# Could not get a command to work with bash -c

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am trying to execute a command to find out which process is listening on a particular port and i cannot get it to work if the command is passed as an argument to bash using `bash -c`

```
netstat -tnlp 2>/dev/null | grep ':10301' 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10301           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4755/nc
```

I can get it working if i do the below and it shows nc is listening on that port

```
netstat -tnlp 2>/dev/null | grep ':10301'  | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs -i -n1 cat /proc/{}/cmdline
nc-kl10301
```

but if do it using bash -c

```
bash -c "netstat -tnlp 2>/dev/null | grep ':10301'  | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs -i -n1 cat /proc/{}/cmdline"
cat: /proc/tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10301           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4755/cmdline: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `$` in double quotes,

```
bash -c "netstat -tnlp 2>/dev/null | grep ':10301'  | grep LISTEN | awk '{print \$7}' | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs -i -n1 cat /proc/{}/cmdline"
```

In your case, `$7` is interpreted as a parameter. So `awk` will run `{print}` which prints the whole line instead of the intended field.